# Projecting single element of array in embedded document

Tags: arrays, mongodb, projection

I have a collection with documents that have several layers of nesting, and the bottom level contains some arrays. For instance, something like

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("56cad039213484920df2"),
    "foo": "this",
    "res": {
       "res1": {
           "t1": [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
               }
           }
    ...
}
```

Now I want to query for a single array index on the bottom level of nesting. I can manage to access the *entire* array with something like

```
db.my_db.find({'foo': 'this'}, {'res.res1.t1': 1})
```

But then [from the documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/#project-specific-array-elements-in-the-returned-array), I thought that in order to access a *single* element of this array, let's say at index 2, I should use `$slice`.

```
db.my_db.find({'foo': 'this'}, {'res.res1.t1': {$slice: 2}})
```

However this doesn't seem to work, instead just giving me full documents back.

**My question is then**, how do I project a single element of an array in an embedded document?

<sup>I'm using Mongo version 3.4.1.</sup>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `$slice` to get first(1), last(-1) and any slice. `$slice:2` will give you first two elements `[1, 1]`.

You need to use aggregation for any other indexed value.

Use `$arrayElemAt` aggregator operator to project the index value from array.

Something like

`db.my_db.aggregate({$match:{'foo': 'this'}}, {$project:{'element2': {$arrayElemAt: ['$res.res1.t1', 1]}}})`